# Groupby conditional statement using Pandas and Numpy

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, pandas

I have a data frame created using pandas as following:

```
       0          1
0   1985   4.274394
1   1985   0.043272
2   1985   0.000000
3   1986   1.835303
4   1986   0.046057
.   ....   ........
```

I like to use year column from above and apply following steps as condition in groupby so that only those yearly values are returned which are greater than condition:

```
b = sorted(a, reverse = False) # 'a' is list (column 1 from above)
c = np.array(b)
d = np.diff(np.cumsum(c) >= sum(c) * 0.60)
e = np.array(d).tolist()
```

Any help would be appreciative.

Answer (score 1):

From your data:

```
import pandas as pd
u=pd.read_csv('data.txt',sep='\s+')     # from your data
```

First prepare:

```
us = u.sort(['0','1'],ascending=[1,0])
g=us.groupby('0')
us2=us.merge(g.sum().reset_index(),'left','0')
us2.columns=['year','value','gsum']
us2['gcumsum']=g.cumsum()
```

then us2 is :

```
   year     value      gsum   gcumsum
0  1985  4.274394  4.317666  4.274394
1  1985  0.043272  4.317666  4.317666
2  1985  0.000000  4.317666  4.317666
3  1986  1.835303  1.881360  1.835303
4  1986  0.046057  1.881360  1.881360
```

Second, select :

```
select=us2[us2.gcumsum>us2.gsum*.6]
g2=select.groupby('year').first()
```

g2 is :

```
         value      gsum   gcumsum
year                              
1985  4.274394  4.317666  4.274394
1986  1.835303  1.881360  1.835303
```

Comment: pandas now support `sort_values()`. Also, should I only use `select=us2[us2.gcumsum>us2.gsum*.6]` to get values greater than 60% of all values?